# symfony2 logger in profiler

Tags: symfony, logging, profiler

I looked for this info in this forum and many others but I can't understand how to log messages in the profiler.

I attempt to log messages from my controller.

CalendarController.php :

```php
<?php

namespace DJU\CalendarBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleExceptionEvent;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;



class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    protected $logger;
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getweekAction() {
        $this->logger->info("this is a test message");
    }
}
```

According to what I've read in the symfony doc, I've also modified the config.yml

app/config/config.yml

```css
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_VERBOSE: INFO
                VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE: DEBUG
            channels: ["!doctrine"]
        console_very_verbose:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_VERBOSE: NOTICE
                VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE: NOTICE
                VERBOSITY_DEBUG: DEBUG
            channels: ["doctrine"]
```

This is a simple copy paste from the config_dev.yml.

No log appears in the profiler.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: you correct see your message in the dev.log files?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using constructor in controller class then you should use [controller as service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) to inject logger there.
Normally if you want to call logger service from controller you can simply get it from container:

```
class CalendarController extends Controller
{ 
    public function getweekAction() {
        $this->get('logger')->info("this is a test message");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Artem. Thank you. I've removed the constructor function accordingly and just leave the command you mentioned in your post without success again. I've also looked in the app/log/dev.log but can't find my "this is a test". Should I have to remove the monolog configuration in the config.yml too?

Comment: I tried with your monolog configuration and had success with it. You should dig in another place then i think.

Comment: Yeah you were right. Thank you I review my routes and found that I wasn't on the right controller... Thanks again Artem

Answer (score 0):

what version of symfony?  if you're on symfony 2.6 or higher you can just do `dump('some log');` and it will appear in the profiler.

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer.My version is 2.6.6, I've tried the dump command without success I still have nothing in the log (debug or info) nor in the dump.